# How can i get match information with python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem with extracting data using the request library.

I want to get the time of the match, the name of the teams, the odds for the result from the
[nesine.com](https://www.nesine.com/iddaa?et=1&lc=584%7C1980&le=1&ocg=MS-2%2C5&gt=Pop%C3%BCler)

Example:

```
Match time: 19.00
Team Name 1 : Boluspor
Team Name 2 : Menemen
Match Result (1) : 2.10
Match Result (X) : 2.65
Match Result (2) : 2.65
Match Result (Lower) : 1.55
Match Result (Upper) : 1.75
```

I tried a lot of myself for this, but none of them were positive.
This is one of the codes I've tried

```
    r = requests.get("https://www.nesine.com/iddaa?et=1&lc=584%7C1980&le=1&ocg=MS-2%2C5&gt=Pop%C3%BCler")
    source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    times = source.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"time"})
    names = source.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"name"})
    return times,names
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct address you're calling here? When I input that link in a browser, it loads the website and only after that it starts loading in the statistics. I'd suggest printing out the text response of your request and manually see if you can even find what you're looking for that way. If that's not the case, you might want to check network traffic in chrome for example to see what the actual address would be.

Comment: @DrRonne When I enter the site, I can see the data I want to retrieve, but when I use the "get" function from the request library, the data is not visible.

Comment: That's what I mean though. There's a difference between seeing it in your browser and doing one get request. Your browser does one get request to the link you entered first, but then it also does a lot of other requests after that to gather extra resources that the first page refers to. If you're using the requests library, it does not do that, it only makes the initial request without gathering the extra resources. The data you're after might be in one of those extra resources. And to find that, you could analyze network traffic using google chrome for example.

Comment: the website fetches data from an API: https://bulten.nesine.com/api/bulten/getprebultenfull

Comment: Sorry. Now I know what you mean. I enter the site, then the site gives the matches according to my time and location. Therefore, python returns null to me. 
So what do you think I can do?

Comment: First of all thanks @dh762 but I want to ask a question. How did you find this link?

Comment: through https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/ - but there's an in-depth answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's first worth understanding *why* you can't use `requests` to retrieve this data in the way you are doing, but also *how* you may be able to do it.

`requests` workflow is rather quite simple - the `.get()` function sends an HTTP request to the server requesting relevant resources about the page. The server then replies with the relevant HTML, CSS, and Javascript that composes the page. This server, like many, does not reply with the entirety of the page, and instead, using the Javascript in which the server responds back to the client it *further* loads more information into the page. This is visually obvious when you load the website and you see a "loading" symbol inside the frame in which you are trying to request information from, but it becomes more apparent when you do a quick analysis in the **Network** tab of your Inspect Element.

[image]

At around 1,500ms to 2,500ms my browser sends a new request to the an API endpoint that seems to pull the relevant information that you seek (I only knew this after further digging around - not some crazy intuition). Compare this with http://example.com, you can see how a simple HTML & CSS website only replies with the initial `GET` data:

[image]

To extract the information you are looking for, then, you must look through the **Network** tab and see *how* your browser is pulling the data from the server. Doing a quick "Find" for the word `Boluspor` we get the following results:

[image]

Now that we know *where* the API request is, then we can query it with `requests` to get the relevant information. I recommend first clicking the url of *where* the actual results are coming in from and select "Copy as fetch", which you will get the following:

```
fetch("https://bulten.nesine.com/api/bulten/getprebultenfull", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "authorization": "Basic RDQ3MDc4RDMtNjcwQi00OUJBLTgxNUYtM0IyMjI2MTM1MTZCOkI4MzJCQjZGLTQwMjgtNDIwNS05NjFELTg1N0QxRTZEOTk0OA==",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site"
  },
  "referrer": "https://www.nesine.com/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

The above alone doesn't seem to indicate that there is anything special going on in the request (e.g. headers, params, etc.), so accessing the endpoint alone should work -- and that is the case:

https://bulten.nesine.com/api/bulten/getprebultenfull

You can then use `requests` to grab that page, load it via the `json` module, and begin organizing the data.