# I am trying to scrape a website using python request that doesn't change its link when click on load more i tried but looks its json

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape all the add links from a site and have I been successful in doing so. please check the link
https://www.olx.in/hyderabad_g4058526/q-note-9-pro?isSearchCall=true

The site page has a load more button for loading more adds.
[1]: [https://ibb.co/DGNsG6j"](https://ibb.co/DGNsG6j%22)

The problem is that clicking on load more doesn't change the URL of the page, therefore I'm being able to scrape only the initial links displayed by default Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Look into their private API; Inspect Element, and Network tab. Notice when you click the 'Load More' button your browser makes a request to the following URL:

```
https://www.olx.in/api/relevance/v2/search?facet_limit=100&lang=en&latitude=17.46497&location=4058526&location_facet_limit=20&longitude=78.43517&page=1&platform=web-desktop&query=note%209%20pro&spellcheck=true
```

You can modify the query via the URL params. Then, using `requests`, you can query this information and organize the JSON return:

```json
{
  "version": "100.0",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1636448838",
      "score": 1679.043212890625,
      "spell": {
        "id": 54,
        "key": "GEAS",
        "version": "1",
        "main": true,
        "facet_disabled": false,
        "default_sorting": "DEFAULT"
      },
      "status": {
        "status": "active",
        "allow_edit": true,
        "ban_reason_id": null,
        "display": "active",
        "translated_display": "Active",
        "link": null,
        "flags": {
          "new": false,
          "hot": false
        },
        "message": null
      },
      "category_id": "1453",
      "favorites": {
        "count": 0,
        "count_label_next": "1"
      },
      "images": [
        {
          "id": "1003855963",
          "external_id": "tj7vu6vj98qp-IN",
          "width": 524,
          "height": 1080,
          "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/tj7vu6vj98qp-IN/image",
          "full": {
            "width": 1080,
            "height": 2225,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/tj7vu6vj98qp-IN/image;s=1080x2225"
          },
          "big": {
            "width": 505,
            "height": 1040,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/tj7vu6vj98qp-IN/image;s=505x1040"
          },
          "medium": {
            "width": 120,
            "height": 247,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/tj7vu6vj98qp-IN/image;s=120x247"
          },
          "small": {
            "width": 120,
            "height": 247,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/tj7vu6vj98qp-IN/image;s=120x247"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "1003855964",
          "external_id": "s6z25cvcbz052-IN",
          "width": 524,
          "height": 1080,
          "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/s6z25cvcbz052-IN/image",
          "full": {
            "width": 1080,
            "height": 2225,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/s6z25cvcbz052-IN/image;s=1080x2225"
          },
          "big": {
            "width": 505,
            "height": 1040,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/s6z25cvcbz052-IN/image;s=505x1040"
          },
          "medium": {
            "width": 120,
            "height": 247,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/s6z25cvcbz052-IN/image;s=120x247"
          },
          "small": {
            "width": 120,
            "height": 247,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/s6z25cvcbz052-IN/image;s=120x247"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "1003855965",
          "external_id": "mq6ouyke1k3h3-IN",
          "width": 524,
          "height": 1080,
          "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/mq6ouyke1k3h3-IN/image",
          "full": {
            "width": 1080,
            "height": 2225,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/mq6ouyke1k3h3-IN/image;s=1080x2225"
          },
          "big": {
            "width": 505,
            "height": 1040,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/mq6ouyke1k3h3-IN/image;s=505x1040"
          },
          "medium": {
            "width": 120,
            "height": 247,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/mq6ouyke1k3h3-IN/image;s=120x247"
          },
          "small": {
            "width": 120,
            "height": 247,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/mq6ouyke1k3h3-IN/image;s=120x247"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "1003855966",
          "external_id": "7vfcbj5fb8fh2-IN",
          "width": 524,
          "height": 1080,
          "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/7vfcbj5fb8fh2-IN/image",
          "full": {
            "width": 1080,
            "height": 2225,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/7vfcbj5fb8fh2-IN/image;s=1080x2225"
          },
          "big": {
            "width": 505,
            "height": 1040,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/7vfcbj5fb8fh2-IN/image;s=505x1040"
          },
          "medium": {
            "width": 120,
            "height": 247,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/7vfcbj5fb8fh2-IN/image;s=120x247"
          },
          "small": {
            "width": 120,
            "height": 247,
            "url": "https://apollo-singapore.akamaized.net:443/v1/files/7vfcbj5fb8fh2-IN/image;s=120x247"
          }
        }
      ],
      "certified_car": false,
      "is_kyc_verified_user": false,
      "has_phone_param": false,
      "locations_resolved": {
        "COUNTRY_id": "1000001",
        "COUNTRY_name": "India",
        "ADMIN_LEVEL_1_id": "2007599",
        "ADMIN_LEVEL_1_name": "Telangana",
        "ADMIN_LEVEL_3_id": "4058526",
        "ADMIN_LEVEL_3_name": "Hyderabad",
        "SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_1_id": "5348837",
        "SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_1_name": "Murad Nagar"
      },
      "description": "Full condition with box + bill charger",
      "created_at": "2021-05-18T10:53:54+05:30",
      "inspection_info": null,
      "package_id": null,
      "title": "Note 9 pro",
      "main_info": null,
      "user_type": "Regular",
      "display_date": "2021-05-18T05:23:54+0000",
      "user_id": "508731436",
      "price": {
        "value": {
          "raw": 14500,
          "currency": {
            "iso_4217": "INR",
            "pre": "₹"
          },
          "display": "₹ 14,500"
        },
        "key_name": "Price",
        "key": "price"
      },
      "created_at_first": "2021-05-18T10:53:54+05:30",
      "locations": [
        {
          "lat": 17.39,
          "lon": 78.448,
          "region_id": "2007599",
          "district_id": "5348837",
          "city_id": "4058526"
        }
      ],
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "single",
          "key": "make",
          "value": "mi-phone",
          "key_name": "Brand",
          "formatted_value": "Mi",
          "value_name": "Mi"
        }
      ],
      "monetizationInfo": null
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "offset": 0,
        "criterion": "less_than",
        "distance": 10,
        "relaxation_type": "bucket"
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "offset": 39,
        "criterion": "less_than",
        "distance": 20,
        "relaxation_type": "bucket"
      }
    ],
    "feed_version": "100.0",
    "total_ads": 190,
    "total_suggested_ads": 0,
    "ads_on_page": 20,
    "total_pages": 4,
    "suggested_sections": [],
    "original_term": "note 9 pro",
    "modified_term": "note 9 pro",
    "original_label": "Showing results for ${original_term}",
    "show_hint": false,
    "show_original_items": true,
    "show_suggested_items": false,
    "filters": [
      {
        "id": "price",
        "values": [],
        "display_order": 200,
        "description": "Budget",
        "range": [
          {
            "id": "min",
            "description": "min",
            "min_value": 0,
            "max_value": 10000000000
          },
          {
            "id": "max",
            "description": "max",
            "min_value": 0,
            "max_value": 10000000000
          }
        ],
        "type": "range-input",
        "render_as": "range-input"
      }
    ],
    "applied_sorting": {
      "key": "desc-creation"
    },
    "next_page_url": "http://api.olx.in/relevance/v2/search?facet_limit=100&clientId=pwa&location_facet_limit=20&spellcheck=true&latitude=17.46497&query=note%209%20pro&location=4058526&page=2&lang=en&clientVersion=7.10.1&platform=web-desktop&longitude=78.43517",
    "applied_filters": [],
    "search_query": "note 9 pro",
    "modified_filters": {}
  },
  "empty": false,
  "not_empty": true,
  "suggested_data": []
}
```

I deleted all item entries except one above.

Comment: Thankyou Mr Felipe  sorry for late response please can you give me a solution with code i would be  appreciated please check my code below

Comment: Tell me what you are having difficulties with, and I'll try to help.

Comment: i want to get all data from all pages of that website from load more using requests or beautifulsoup

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537666/how-can-i-get-match-information-with-python/64538195#64538195) answer. It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Selenium? It is able to click through websites automatically by locating HTML tags and clicking links. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html